# How eclipse detect that project is already exist and instead of creating that project, importing it?

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I noticed one intelligent behaviour of Eclipse. I am currently using Eclipse Luna but I think this feature is available in every Eclipse version.

I went to **File-->New-->Java Project** and gave the project Name "***Test***" and clicked **Finish**. So my Java project had created.
I also created one package and one class inside that package.After that I right clicked on the Test project and went to **Delete**.
When I clicked Delete I got the below pop up message

[image]
and I clicked on the OK button.

**Note**: The "Delete project contents on disk(can not be undone)" check box was **unchecked**.

When I again felt I need a Java project, I went to **File-->New-->Java Project** and gave the project Name "***Test***"  and clicked Finish.The existing 
"Test" project was imported.

Does any one has any clue how eclipse detect that project is already exist and instead of creating that project, importing it?

### Note

After delete the project from Eclipse, I manually deleted both `.project` and `.classpath` from that folder and tried to create the Test project. It is still importing without fail.

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse, but it says it's deleting it from the **workspace**. This **isn't** the disk; which is why the option to completely delete it is a separate checkbox. It probably still keeps the project files wherever Eclipse stores its files, but with a special value set such that Eclipse knows not to display it. That's only a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a project in a folder that already contains a project, i.e. has a file named `.project`, then Elipse will detect that. By default when creating projects, they are all created as subfolders of your workspace, so re-creating a project with the same name, will use the same folder.

Comment: But after delete the project from Eclipse, I manually deleted both `.project` and `.classpath` from that folder and tried to create the Test project. It is still importing without fail.why?

Comment: @Pitchers You didn't delete the `.java` files, right? So they are still there. Deleting the `.project` and `.classpath` files means you lost the *settings* only.

Comment: Yes, I did not deleted the `.java` file.But I am not getting how eclipse detect the existing project?

Comment: It didn't detect the project. It created a new project with your existing source files.